# Comparing Drawables android

Tags: java, android

I am really stuck trying to compare two drawables. I added a picture in my project and set it as a buttons background in XML.

Now I want to check the clicked buttons background drawable with my project drawable. I tried so many things but no luck at all.

I tried this code also -

```
    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myImageBtn);
    Drawable drawable = btn.getDrawable();
    if (drawable.getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myDrawable).getConstantState())){
       //Do your work here
    }
```

But it gives me an error

Comment: yes, comparing `ConstantState` is the way you should follow

Comment: set getContext() or this instead  getResources() . i am not sure is it perfect or not

Comment: @Sajid If not working please shows your logcat errors

Comment: I managed to do this using setTag and getTag. Thank u all :)